# Users and groups support for Azure AD App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Quick question with regards to App registration vs Enterprise applications, in order to control who can access a custom developed application:

- When one registers a new app in the App registration blade and
  selects organizational directory only, Azure does not allow to
  restrict this app to a few select users and/or groups within this
  tenant; with this the approach is to solve this within the app, by
  using the exposed claims (groups, app roles, etc.). Correct?
- When one registers the same app by using the Enterprise applications blade,
  the user and groups and also conditional access feature can be used
  in order to restrict who can access the app. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict access to custom apps in the same way.
An "enterprise application" aka service principal is always created for app registrations.
If you open the app registration, you can click "Managed application in local directory" to navigate to the service principal.

That's this link in the bottom right of the image:

[image: Link to managed application in local directory on overview page of app registration]

From there you can decide which users should be allowed to log in etc.

Comment: I don't see "Managed application in local directory" anywhere in my app registration.

Comment: @AndrWeisR I added a screenshot where you can find it